# Independent/unpaired t-test assumption of independent observation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, assumptions

I am just wondering if unpaired/independent t-test assumes each observation is not related?

For instance, in our data there were group A and B. In group B, there were 3 subjects that were observed multiple times, e.g.

**Subject in Group B**

| subject_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| sub_1 | 0.01 |
| sub_1 | 0.01 |
| sub_2 | 0.029 |
| sub_2 | 0.03 |
| sub_3 | 0.013 |
| sub_3 | 0.014 |
| sub_1 | 0.009 |
| sub_4 | 0.016 |
| sub_5 | 0.015 |
| sub_6 | 0.018 |

Does fetching these data as is violating one of the t-test’s assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this violates the assumption of a t-test. This kind of situation typically calls for some form of repeated measures method. If one wrongly treats multiple observations from the same subject as independent, then especially the standard errors will wrongly much too small.

E.g. if these are otherwise undistinguishable (i.e. you know nothing why one would be higher or lower, no extra information could explain differences etc.) observations that measure the exact same thing, but you just measured several times on the same individual (example, if I measure someone's weight 5 times in 10 minutes because the scales give slightly variable results, then I wouldn't think there would be any reason to think any of these measurement are more or less likely to be higher than the others), then something like a linear model with a random subject effect on the intercept could be an appropriate choice. To use R syntax that would work e.g. with the `lme4` package something like `lmer(value ~ (1|subject_id) + group, data=mydata)`.

Comment: Thank you!! How about if the data comes from biopsy, but those samples were different specimens, coming from the same subjects? I guess that should still be related, hence still violates the assumption, right?

Comment: In general, yes. I guess it depends a bit on the biological details, but most definitely if when you see one measurement from a person and it's, say, a very high (low) measurement, if that tells you anything about what you'd expect from the next measurement for the person - such as that it's not very likely to then be very low (high). If the data shows a low correlation within subjects, then you'll gain more from the extra records and when the correlation is high the extra records per person will be "worth less".

Comment: I see! Anyway, is there any reliable link/paper that mentioned the assumption of independent observation in unpaired t-test, so I could reference it? Most of the resources I looked at just say that the 2 groups should be independent.

Comment: There's plenty of pubs in areas where this happens a lot e.g. due to multiple eyes/teeth in the same patient being treated/not-treated in randomized trials (very well recognized in those areas). 

See e.g. Glynn, R. J., & Rosner, B. (1992). Accounting for the correlation between fellow eyes in regression analysis. Archives of ophthalmology, 110(3), 381-387. 
or 
Pandis, N., Walsh, T., Polychronopoulou, A., Katsaros, C., & Eliades, T. (2013). Split-mouth designs in orthodontics: an overview with applications to orthodontic clinical trials. European Journal of Orthodontics, 35(6), 783-789.

Comment: There's of course also anything that's written on mixed model for repeated measures analyses, on which you can probably google and find tons of relevant papers discussing different settings.